# How do I call a dynamically-named method in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, methods

I am working on dynamically creating some JavaScript that will be inserted into a web page as it's being constructed.

The JavaScript will be used to populate a `listbox` based on the selection in another `listbox`. When the selection of one `listbox` is changed it will call a method name based on the selected value of the `listbox`.

For example:

`Listbox1` contains:

- `Colours`
- `Shapes`

If `Colours` is selected then it will call a `populate_Colours` method that populates another `listbox`.

To clarify my question: How do I make that `populate_Colours` call in JavaScript?

Comment: I'd recommend against this in favour of having local branches in a single 'populate' method. It would make it more testable and look less "hacky"

Comment: see my answer here. [call by name in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46090820/7771019)

Answer (score 245, accepted):

Assuming the `populate_Colours` method is in the global namespace, you may use the following code, which exploits both that all object properties may be accessed as though the object were an associative array, and that all global objects are actually properties of the `window` host object.

```js
var method_name = "Colours";
var method_prefix = "populate_";

// Call function:
window[method_prefix + method_name](arg1, arg2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The 'window' bit really threw me until I googled it and found that global objects are part of the window object. Now it makes sense! Thank you.

FYI I found a good page about it here
 http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2009/02/09/javascript-5-ways-to-call-a-function.aspx

Comment: I did something similar except the functions I was targeting were in the jQuery "fn" namespace. For example, `$.fn[method_prefix + method_name](arg1, arg2);`

Comment: Nice. Worth adding a `try`/`catch` block, perhaps.

Comment: This may be obvious to some, but for those that can't get it to work: throw the function outside your `$(function () {` and `window.load` code :)

Comment: How to call this type of functions dynamically?
`alertify.[dynamicFunctionName](var);`
??

Comment: Why can't you use `['alert']('Hi')` since the window namespace is the default namespace?

Comment: @peter Because square brackets are not property accessors in this context, but denote an Array. Arrays are not functions, so you can’t call them.

Comment: @SizzlingCode You can’t use dot notation and bracket notation at the same time.

Comment: Why nobody raised the issue of polluting the global object? Especially with such generic names. Beware, this approach will bite you seriously as you build the system comprising more than 2-3 external libs.

Comment: read this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417274/call-a-function-from-dynamically-added-html-code-using-jquery

Answer (score 51):

I would recommend **NOT** to use `global` / `window` / `eval` for this purpose.
Instead, do it this way:

define all methods as properties of Handler:

```
var Handler={};

Handler.application_run = function (name) {
console.log(name)
}
```

Now call it like this

```
var somefunc = "application_run";
Handler[somefunc]('jerry');
```

**Output:** jerry

---

Case when importing functions from different files

```
import { func1, func2 } from "../utility";

const Handler= {
  func1,
  func2
};

Handler["func1"]("sic mundus");
Handler["func2"]("creatus est");
```

Comment: why NOT to use `global` / `window` / `eval`?

Answer (score 48):

As Triptych points out, you can call any global scope function by finding it in the host object's contents.

A cleaner method, which pollutes the global namespace much less, is to explicitly put the functions into an array directly like so:

```
var dyn_functions = [];
dyn_functions['populate_Colours'] = function (arg1, arg2) { 
                // function body
           };
dyn_functions['populate_Shapes'] = function (arg1, arg2) { 
                // function body
           };
// calling one of the functions
var result = dyn_functions['populate_Shapes'](1, 2);
// this works as well due to the similarity between arrays and objects
var result2 = dyn_functions.populate_Shapes(1, 2);
```

This array could also be a property of some object other than the global host object too meaning that you can effectively create your own namespace as many JS libraries such as jQuery do. This is useful for reducing conflicts if/when you include multiple separate utility libraries in the same page, and (other parts of your design permitting) can make it easier to reuse the code in other pages.

You could also use an object like so, which you might find cleaner:

```
var dyn_functions = {};
dyn_functions.populate_Colours = function (arg1, arg2) { 
                // function body
           };
dyn_functions['populate_Shapes'] = function (arg1, arg2) { 
                // function body
           };
// calling one of the functions
var result = dyn_functions.populate_Shapes(1, 2);
// this works as well due to the similarity between arrays and objects
var result2 = dyn_functions['populate_Shapes'](1, 2);
```

Note that with either an array or an object, you can use either method of setting or accessing the functions, and can of course store other objects in there too. You can further reduce the syntax of either method for content that isn't that dynamic by using JS literal notation like so:

```
var dyn_functions = {
           populate_Colours:function (arg1, arg2) { 
                // function body
           };
         , populate_Shapes:function (arg1, arg2) { 
                // function body
           };
};
```

Edit: of course for larger blocks of functionality you can expand the above to the very common "module pattern" which is a popular way to encapsulate code features in an organised manner.

Comment: That's a nice way of keeping it clean. How would I call the method though? Would window[dyn_functions['populate_Colours'](arg1, arg2) work?

Comment: Answering my own question - I've just tested window[dyn_functions['populate_Colours'](arg1,arg2)];
and it does indeed work.

Comment: As epascarello points out, you usually don't need "window" - "dyn_functions['populate_Colours'](arg1,arg2);" will work. In fact not including the global object's name will make code more portable if you are writing routines that might ever be used in a JS environment other than a web browser. There is an exception to this though: if you have a local variable called dyn_functions in a function then you would need to be more specific which you are referring to, but this situation is best avoided (by having sensible naming conventions) anyway.

Comment: Since this post is from '09 you probably know this by now, but you're creating an array, then assigning to the array's properties (not indexes). You might as well do `var dyn_functions = {};` so you don't needlessly create an array... this isn't a huge issue though.

Comment: overly complicated answer but does work.  I would think the resource load for scenario where I have series of patterned functions and i need a decision tree to choose the execution, this method might be overly complex to perform the task.  Albeit, if I was wiring up my own class object, this would be the preferred approach to defining the object itself.

Comment: This is more generic and better than having global functions in window object.

Answer (score 20):

you can do it like this:

```
function MyClass() {
    this.abc = function() {
        alert("abc");
    }
}

var myObject = new MyClass();
myObject["abc"]();
```

Answer (score 6):

Within a `ServiceWorker` or `Worker`, replace `window` with `self`:

```
self[method_prefix + method_name](arg1, arg2);
```

Workers have no access to the DOM, therefore `window` is an invalid reference. The equivalent global scope identifier for this purpose is `self`.

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't recommend using the window as some of the other answers suggest. Use `this` and scope accordingly.

```
this['yourDynamicFcnName'](arguments);
```

Another neat trick is calling within different scopes and using it for inheritance. Let's say you had nested the function and want access to the global window object. You could do this:

```
this['yourDynamicFcnName'].call(window, arguments);
```

Comment: How can I do it typescript? I have a method in class, which will iterate array of object, which has functionName and function argument. 

To be called functions are present in same class. However I get error as this[functionName](funcArgument) is not a function

Comment: Can you share a codepen example? With classes make sure to think about lexical scope.

Comment: WIll you add an example for doing this when window does not exist like in Node?

Comment: The window doesn't have to exist, I just gave that as an example. You can use any object, and from my memory I think node does have a global `this` scoped to their own object, so the first option should work perfectly in node or the browser.

Answer (score 4):

Just do it

```
class User

  getName() 
  {   

    return "dilo";
   }

}

let user =new User();
let dynamicMethod='getName';
console.log(user[dynamicMethod]()); //dilo
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Simple fundamental answer, works in all types of js, maybe missing { following class User ?

Answer (score 1):

Hi try this,

```
 var callback_function = new Function(functionName);
 callback_function();
```

it will handle the parameters itself.

Comment: uncaught reference error - functionName is not defined

Comment: @brianlmerritt you have to define the value for `functionName`...the answerer made the assumption that you already had that defined.

Comment: It seems new Function() cannot be used like that for this purpose.

Comment: doesnt work for me `g = function(){return 'l'}; var callback_function = new Function(g);`

Answer (score 0):

A simple function to call a function dynamically with parameters:

```js
this.callFunction = this.call_function = function(name) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return window[name].call(this, ...args);
};

function sayHello(name, age) {
    console.log('hello ' + name + ', your\'e age is ' + age);
    return some;
}

console.log(call_function('sayHello', 'john', 30)); // hello john, your'e age is 30
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try These**

Call Functions With Dynamic Names, like this:

```
let dynamic_func_name = 'alert';
(new Function(dynamic_func_name+'()'))()
```

with parameters:

```
let dynamic_func_name = 'alert';
let para_1 = 'HAHAHA';
let para_2 = 'ABCD';
(new Function(`${dynamic_func_name}('${para_1}','${para_2}')`))()
```

Run Dynamic Code:

```
let some_code = "alert('hahaha');";
(new Function(some_code))()
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// FUNCTIONS
const funcs = {

  func1() {
    console.log('func1 accessed');
  },

  func2() {
    console.log('func2 accessed');
  }

}

// DYNAMIC FUNCTION NAME
const nameFunc = 'func2';

// DYNAMIC ACCESS TO FUNCTIONS
funcs[nameFunc]();
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is a working and simple solution for checking **existence of a function** and **triaging that function dynamically** by another function;

Trigger function

```
function runDynmicFunction(functionname){ 

    if (typeof window[functionname] == "function"  ) { //check availability

        window[functionname]("this is from the function it "); //run function and pass a parameter to it
    }
}
```

and you can now generate the function dynamically maybe using php like this

```
function runThis_func(my_Parameter){

    alert(my_Parameter +" triggerd");
}
```

now you can call the function using dynamically generated event

```
<?php

$name_frm_somware ="runThis_func";

echo "<input type='button' value='Button' onclick='runDynmicFunction(\"".$name_frm_somware."\");'>";

?>
```

the exact HTML code you need is

```
<input type="button" value="Button" onclick="runDynmicFunction('runThis_func');">
```

Answer (score -4):

Try with this:

```
var fn_name = "Colours",
fn = eval("populate_"+fn_name);
fn(args1,argsN);
```

Comment: What are the implications of using this pattern?  I have read that the `eval` function has some wierd side-effects related to its use.  I generally try to stay away from it, unless it is a last resort.

Comment: Eval'ing dynamic content makes it very easy for a hacker to inject and execute their own code into yours