# Dynamically call jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do this:

```
var todo = "text";

$this.eval(todo).split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/).length;
```

So that this would be the resulting function:

```
$this.text().split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/).length;
```

I can't figure it out...How do I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I call a dynamically-named method in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969743/how-do-i-call-a-dynamically-named-method-in-javascript) and [others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+call+methods+dynamically)

Comment: Why do you need to call it dynamically like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var todo = 'text';
$this[todo]().split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/).length;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must have it fully dynamic, then you can simply put it all in a string and just eval() it. Something like this:

```
var obj_name = "text";
var eval_code = "$this."+ obj_name + "(todo).split(/\\b[\\s,\\.-:;]*/).length;";
var result = eval(eval_code);
```

Also, don't name your variable eval to avoid conflicts with the eval function.

Hope that helps!

Comment: `eval` is not necessary here.

Comment: I completely agree. However, the original poster was asking about using a variable as part of a line of code. That's why I said "if you must have it fully dynamic". It's not the right or even good solution, but it answers his question of embedding a variable into a block of code. But yes, it should be clarified that this is not even close to an efficient solution.