# Knockout.js and dynamic string function not working

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-templates

Below I am rendering on the second else an object that contains a string for `action.DataBind` that renders `app.viewModel.members.divisionPools.addPool();`  the click event isnt working.  Am I doing something wrong?

```
    {{if action.IsDownload }}
                    <a href="#" data-bind="download: { url: 'members/' + action.Route().toLowerCase() }">${Title}</a>
    {{else action.DataBind}}
                    <a href="#" data-bind="click: action.DataBind">${Title}</a>
    {{else}}
                    <a href="#" data-bind="attr: { href: app.viewModel.members.createRoute(action) }">${Title}</a>
    {{/if}}

app.viewModel.members.divisionPools = {
        addPool: function () {
            alert('test');  
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

You mention that `action.DataBind` is a string. This will not work, a 'click' binding expects a function, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call javascript functions dynamically I would take a look at [How do I call a dynamically-named method in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969743/how-do-i-call-a-dynamically-named-method-in-javascript)

In your markup you would have something along the lines of:

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click: function() { myViewModel.callDynamicFunction($data.action.DataBind) }">
```

and on your view model add the function:

```
callDynamicFunction: function(funcName) { .. call function dynamically ... }
```