# Call a function from Dynamically added html code using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the scenario

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var rowIndex = 0;
 var count = 0;
 function callThisFunction(index, value, count) {
 alert('called');
}

function dynamicContentAdd() {
 rowIndex++;
 count++;

 var row = "<input name='input["+rowIndex+"]' onkeyup = 'callThisFunction("+rowIndex+","+total[1]+","+count+");' id='input"+rowIndex+"'  type='text' class='inputfield' />";

 $("#table").append(row);
}
```

I have called the function dynamicContentAdd() on click of a button and it is working fine. But what is not working is it is not calling function callThisFunction() on keyup. It gives the error that the function is not defined. But when I have the same function in external js file then it calls it successfully. Is this not the way to call the function from dynamic added html code in jquery.

Please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is since you are using inlined event handlers the js engine will look for the function `callThisFunction` in the global scope, but you have added the function in the dom ready handler making it a local function to the dom ready handler which will result in the js throwing an error.

Solution 1. make the function global

```
//since the function is define outside of dom ready handler it is available in the global scope
function callThisFunction(index, value, count) {
    alert('called');
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var rowIndex = 0;
    var count = 0;

    function dynamicContentAdd() {
        rowIndex++;
        count++;

        var row = "<input name='input[" + rowIndex + "]' onkeyup = 'callThisFunction(" + rowIndex + "," + total[1] + "," + count + ");' id='input" + rowIndex + "'  type='text' class='inputfield' />";

        $("#table").append(row);
    }
})
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var rowIndex = 0;
    var count = 0;

    //define the function as a property of the window object again making it available in the public scope
    window.callThisFunction = function (index, value, count) {
        alert('called');
    }

    function dynamicContentAdd() {
        rowIndex++;
        count++;

        var row = "<input name='input[" + rowIndex + "]' onkeyup = 'callThisFunction(" + rowIndex + "," + total[1] + "," + count + ");' id='input" + rowIndex + "'  type='text' class='inputfield' />";

        $("#table").append(row);
    }
})
```

Solution 2: The jQuery way - Use a delegated event handler with data-* attributes

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var rowIndex = 0;
    var count = 0;

    $('#table').on('keyup',  '.myfncaller', function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var index = $this.data('index'), value = $this.data('value'), count = $this.data('count');
    })

    function dynamicContentAdd() {
        rowIndex++;
        count++;

        var row = "<input name='input[" + rowIndex + "]' id='input" + rowIndex + "'  type='text' class='inputfield myfncaller' data-index='" + rowIndex + "' data-value='" + total[1] + "' data-count='" + count + "' />";

        $("#table").append(row);
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked indeed. I chose the second option of Solution1

Comment: wow this has worked . well i have learnt something new , thanks @Arun P Johny