# Calling A javascript function via a form of reflection? in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I have these two javascript functions:

```
function some_name(say_something){
    console.log('hello' + say_something);
}

call_other_fuction_after_doing_something('some_function')


// In some other file, some where - in the land of make believe.
function call_other_fuction_after_doing_something(function_name){
    $.ajax({
        url : /*Go some where*/,
    type : 'POST'
    data : { /*Some kind of data*/},
    success : function(result){
        if(function_name !== undefined){
        $.fn[success_action](result); // Pay attention to this!
        }
    },
    });
}
```

So as we can see I do some function in some file, some where that logs to the console: "hello"  which then has what ever the result is that comes back from the ajax call appended to it.

I assumed this would work, as I read something about this [here in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969743/how-do-i-call-a-dynamically-named-method-in-javascript). But apparently I was wrong as the error I get is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'some_name'
```

Any ideas how to do this kind of "Reflection" in javascript (jquery)?

Comment: why do you want to pass the function name, why can't you pass the function reference itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is to call a function which is a property of `$.fn`, which it looks like does not exists.

Try passing the function reference instead of name

```
function some_name(say_something){
    console.log('hello' + say_something);
}

call_other_fuction_after_doing_something(some_name)


//In some other file, some where - in the land of make believe.
function call_other_fuction_after_doing_something(fn){
    $.ajax({
        url : /*Go some where*/,
    type : 'POST'
    data : { /*Some kind of data*/},
    success : function(result){
        if(typeof fn == 'function'){
            fn(result); // Pay attention to this!
        }
    },
    });
}
```

Comment: The function in question, spelling mistakes aside, `some_name` is never called, if I do a console.log(fn) out side the if statement and inside I get just the outside coming back with: `some_name` ...

Comment: can you do a `console.log(typeof fn)` outside the `if`

Comment: it comes back and sais string. I am passing by reference, as stated in your example, not by string name.

Comment: @KyleAdams no... you are passing it as a string... otherwise it should have returned function

Comment: I legit coppied your example, replaced url and data with my stuff and ran it and got string instead of function