# Select a constructor function based on a string parameter?

Tags: javascript, constructor

You can use bracket notation to fetch an object:

```
var items = {};
items.obj1 = {};

var type = 'obj1';
var myFunc = function(type){
    var newObj = items[type]; //returns items.obj1
};
```

How can you do the same to dynamically create an object using constructor functions?

```
var Constructor1 = function() {};
var Constructor2 = function() {};

var type = 'Constructor2';
var myFunc = function(type){
   var newObj = new type(); // how do you invoke either constructor?
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, try the following:

```
var myFunc = function(type) {
  return new window[type]();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it seems similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/969756/1837472; I'll have a play.