# How do I call a jQuery function with a dynamic name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

I can't believe that I've been unable to dig out a solution to this problem. It looked to me like a very "regular" problem whose solution would litter the web!

I have these arrays returned from a database query:

```
var ids = ['12', '15', '40'];
var actions = ['hide', 'show', 'fadeIn'];
```

I want to loop through the arrays and carry out the appropriate action on the DOM, like so:

```
for(var i=0; i < ids.length; i++){
    $('#row_'+ids[i]).actions[i]();
}
```

Now you get the idea. Actually I didn't expect the `$('#row_'+ids[i]).actions[i]();` to work as is. I have tried things like

```
$('#row_'+ids[i]).effect(actions[i]);
```

To no avail. I believe `eval()` should work and (in desperation) even tried that but couldn't get the right string for it to work.

Elsewhere on Stack Overflow, I have come across similar issues solved using the `window` global, like:

```
var fn = 'hideSomething';
window.fn();//where hideSomething was a defined function.
```

But this one is defined on `jQuery`, not on `window`.

So here we are!

Comment: dupe : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969743/how-do-i-call-a-dynamically-named-method-in-javascript

Comment: @adeneo: I don't see much jQuery discussion on the page you linked.

Comment: accessing an objects properties is the same, jQuery or not.

Comment: Yeah, I guess so. Sometimes, babies would need spoon-feeding, you know.

Comment: Haba! Why did the other guy delete his answer? Pity, 'cause the brevity is something many will find attractive (me included) often.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `[varhere]` to access a property/method by variable name.  Since your property name is in `actions[i]`, then you would do this:

```
$('#row_'+ids[i])[actions[i]]();
```

Or, in a slightly easier scheme to follow exactly what is happening:

```
var method = actions[i];
$('#row_'+ids[i])[method]();
```

You can use the dot syntax `obj.prop` when the property name is known ahead of time.  When it's in a variable and not known ahead of time, you use the `obj[prop]` syntax.  Since a method is just a property, the same applies to jQuery methods too.

```
for(var i=0; i < ids.length; i++){
    $('#row_'+ids[i])[actions[i]]();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick, helpful and elaborate reply. I guess the "elaborate" will have to win you the acceptance!

Answer (score 2):

Use square bracket notation in order to access the property:

```
for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
  $('#row_' + ids[i])[actions[i]]();
}
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/j7288xj2/)

See: [Property accessors in JS (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

Comment: Thank you for a quick and helpful reply.

Comment: Thank you for undeleting ;)