# Add parameter to a function title

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some functions: `java_2Form()`, `java_4Form()`, `java_6Form()`. I should call one of these functions depending on my need. Can I replace all of them with only one function? For example:

```
function example(form_number) {
  java_' + form_number + 'Form();
}
```

Or something similar?

Comment: As far as I know you can't because `java_'+form_number+'Form()` will become just a string, and not a line of code that calls a function, you will have to work with maybe switch statements and call the desired function.

Comment: You can use `eval()` but you shouldn't. You can also create an object of these methods `var forms = { form1: function (), form2: function () {} };` and then call `var f = 'form1'; forms[f]();` to call `forms.form1()`, which is the same as `forms['form1']()`

Comment: Thanks guys. Works with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969743/how-do-i-call-a-dynamically-named-method-in-javascript