# Dynamically build a function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to dynamically build a function based off another functions parameters?

For example:

**Base Function:**

```
const someFunction = (functionName, functionParams) => {
  // Function Built here
};

someFunction("colorFunction", ["red", true]);
```

**I'd like it to build something similar to this:** *I'd need to deconstruct the Array into individual params, but I'm not sure how simple that is?  And I have no idea how I'd use the first String to call the function name?*

```
functionName(...functionParams);
```

**Which in my head would sort of work like this:**

```
const colorFunction = (color, bool) => {
  console.log("Colour: " + color);
  console.log("Bool: " + bool);
};
```

Bit confused by this - I feel like I'm not a million miles away, but I'm not certain!  Any help would be great, thanks!!

Edit - **Why?**

I have a react component with a click event that fires off a redux action. Ideally this action would fire some stuff over to my reducer, and asynchronously call this "dynamic" function. I can do this with a load of if/elses, but I don't think that's a very clean way of achieving this, if building a function this way is possible.

Comment: Why would you _want_ to do this? Wouldn't it be easier to just do `colorFunction(["red", true])`? The syntax for your custom "function" (I put the word function in quotes because this is really just a glorified function wrapper which doesn't do anything) will always be longer and more annoying track down in the code if issues arise than just using the function directly

Comment: Explain the problem you are trying to solve first in order that others can understand context better

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I have a react component with a click event that fires off to a redux action.  Ideally this action would fire some stuff over to my reducer, and asynchronously call this "dynamic" function.  I can do this with a load of if/elses, but I don't think that's a very clean way of achieving this, if building a function this way is possible.

Comment: @charlietfl I have a react component with a click event that fires off to a redux action.  Ideally this action would fire some stuff over to my reducer, and asynchronously call this "dynamic" function.  I can do this with a load of if/elses, but I don't think that's a very clean way of achieving this, if building a function this way is possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I call a dynamically-named method in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969743/how-do-i-call-a-dynamically-named-method-in-javascript)

Comment: How about [currying or composite patterns](https://medium.com/@pragyan88/writing-middleware-composition-and-currying-elegance-in-javascript-8b15c98a541b)

Comment: Please read this [The XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to determine where the functions you want to call dynamically are stored. If they are global functions then you can call them using `window`:

```
const someFunction = (functionName, functionParams) => {
    window[functionName]();
};
```

If they are methods of an object, then you can do something similar using the object:

```
const someFunction = (functionName, functionParams) => {
    myObject[functionName]();
};
```

As for how to pass the arguments, you have a couple options here. If you are running a recent version of JS, or using polyfills, then you can indeed use the spread operator:

```
const someFunction = (functionName, functionParams) => {
    window[functionName](...functionParams);
};
```

Otherwise you can always rely on the [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Function/apply) method:

```
const someFunction = (functionName, functionParams) => {
    window[functionName].apply(null, functionParams);
};
```

The first argument in the apply method is the context you wish to pass to your function, in your case it doesn't seem necessary, hence the `null` value.

Edit: corrected `bind` with `apply` as mentionned by Bergi

Comment: I'm pretty sure you meant `apply`, not `bind`. And yes, they definitely should be made properties of some local object - global functions should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) in order to make a [thunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk) - basically a function that takes no parameters and it's used for delayed computation.

Using `.bind` you can do a [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application) on a function. In your case, you would just apply all arguments and only leave the execution step at the end:

```js
//your function
const colorFunction = (color, bool) => {
  console.log("Colour: " + color);
  console.log("Bool: " + bool);
};

//partially apply all argument to it

const thunk = colorFunction.bind(null, "red", true);

//this can now be passed around and executed at a later point
setTimeout(thunk, 3000);

console.log("wait 3 seconds");
```

Since functions are [first class members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen) in JavaScript, you can pass any function this way. If you really need a function that turns others into thunks then you can very easily do that:

```
const toThunk = (func, args) => func.bind(null, ...args);
```

Which is your `someFunction` but with just the name and parameters re-named for a bit of clarity.